# Entity framework vs2012 does'n work in vs2008 as reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

In vs2008 I have a problem adding an entity framework project as a reference.
I  wrote Console Application Entity Framework Project in VS2012 and .net 3.5 . 
When I add this project as a reference in other projects in vs2008 I receive this error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=1.0.5000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

That's the error that is raised for system.drawing.dll, but I added system.drawing.dll version 1,2,4 etc as a reference, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i add any entitiy framework to project (even by vs2008 wizard) that raise error.
this is the old reference and component mismatch and not solved for me .
last tow night i was not sleep and switch completely on NHibernate ! 
that's very interesting experience .

Answer (score 0):

While running the project from visual studio force the platform target as 32 bit .

**using following steps:**

```
->Right click on Project
->Select Properties
->Goto Build Options
->Change  "Platform Target" from "ANY CPU" to "X86"
```

Comment: sorry for reject your answer .

Comment: i try to create new console application project in vs 2012 and other one in vs 2008 .both is console application and they are not use any graphical reference . i add vs 2012 output (in dll form) in vs2008 as reference but create error again :

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio
Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'ConsoleApplication1' or one of its dependencies. 
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
OK